# Caffe C++ - Access data in other layers

Tags: c++, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to access the various layers using Caffe C++. However, I am unable to get any data:

```
net_.Forward();

std::vector<std::string> layerNames = net_.layer_names();
for(int i=0; i<layerNames.size(); i++){
    cout << layerNames[i] << endl;
    std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<caffe::Blob<float> > >& layer = net_.layer_by_name(layerNames[i])->blobs();
    cout << layer.size() << endl;
}
```

Above is the approach I used. Even the "data" layer seems to be empty, with a vector size of 0. What is going on here?

Comment: I think you are getting the internal parameters of the layers. `"Data"` layer has no internal parameters and thus you get zero `size` for this layer. Do you get non-zero size for other layers (`"Conv"` and `"InnrrProduct"` layers)?

Comment: You should look at `net_.blobs()` and `net_.blob_names()` instead.

Comment: That seems to work! You can post it as an answer

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code inspect layer's blobs: these are the internal parameters of the net (trainable parameters). `"Data"` layer has no internal parameters, thus the `size` of the blob you got is zero.

On the other hand, if you want to inspect the net's data blobs (i.e., inputs and responses) you should look at `net_.blob_names()` and `net_.blobs()`.